# How do you get the name of a git tag with the JGit API

Tags: java, jgit

I am familiar with using a tag reference to get a Ref and then start doing something:

```
Ref ref = repository.getRef("refs/tags/jena-2.11.2");
```

But if a ref is passed to me and I want to get the "refs/tags/jena-2.11.2" string back, how do I do it with the JGit API?

```
RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);
RevObject object;
try {
    object = walk.parseAny(ref.getObjectId());
} catch (MissingObjectException e) {
     .....
} catch (IOException e) {
     .....
}

if (object instanceof RevTag) {
    // String tagName = object.what?????????
} else if (object instanceof RevCommit) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A commit does not known about the *labels* that may point to it. Therefore there is no `object.getRefs()` or similar.

If you know that there should be a tag pointing to a given commit, you can use the `ListTagCommand` to obtain a list of all tags and then iterate over this list until you found the tag that points to this commit.

The `NameRevCommand` follows a more general approach. Like `git name-rev`, it finds symbolic names for a given commit.

Following your example, this snippet would print the tag name of the commit:

```
Map<ObjectId,String> names = git.nameRev().add( object ).addPrefix( "refs/tags/" ).call();
System.out( names.get( object ) );
```

The `addPrefix` ensures that tags take precedence over other refs in case that more than one ref points to `object`.